# smoothing in fonts in helix framework

Tags: joomla, helix

i use helix for my website. but any font that I insert to it via @font-face not work correctly and text in the screen has some sharp region.
demo: [link to site](http://netbranding.ir/testsite/helixsample/index.php/fa)

note: texts in header and body have two different font.

I guess that this happen because of helix setting. Is it true?

please help me for create a website with smooth text

Answer (score 0):

You have a native feature inside the template for assign multiple fonts to your website.

- Go to **Extensions** > **Templates** > **Your** *Helix* **Template** > **Tab Typography**

  [image]

From here you can add a different font for the body, headings, navigation or enable a custom font for css selectors. This feature works well with *Google Fonts*.

- Here you can find more information: [Typography Settings](https://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix3/typography-settings).